# Kworker threads getting blocked by SCHED_RR userspace threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, real-time

We have a Linux system using kernel 3.14.17, PREEMPT RT. It is a single core system.

For latency issues, our application has some of its threads' scheduling type set to SCHED_RR. However, this causes the kworkers in the kernel to be blocked, as they are only running in mode SCHED_OTHER. This can cause a kind of priority inversion, as a low priority SCHED_RR thread can block a higher priority SHED_RR from receiving the data from the driver.

It is the TTY driver that is being blocked. It uses a work queue in the function tty_flip_buffer_push. Possibly more calls, but that is one we've identified.

Is there any way to easily fix this problem - a RT application being dependent on a kworker? We are hoping we don't have to hack the driver/kernel ourselves. Are there any kernel config options in the RT kernel for this kind of stuff? Can we,

- set a SCHED_RR priority for the kworkers?
- disable work queues for a specific driver?

If we'd have to hack the driver, we'd probably give it its own work queue, with a SCHED_RR kworker.

Of course, any other solution is also of interest. We can upgrade to a later kernel version if there is some new feature.

Comment: Are you using RR priority without CPU pinning? This is doomed to fail.

Comment: Well, we only have a single core. I'll update the question.

Comment: Than you should not use real time priority. As simple as that.

Comment: Why is it not feasible to let the kernel threads run at real-time level?

Comment: Because you have only one CPU.

Comment: And why is it not feasible with only one CPU?

Comment: Because you either have a RR assumes non-preempted, and if you only have one cpu, where the other stuff is going to be executed?

Comment: SCHED_RR means priority based preemption. The idea is to have the kworkers run at some middle priority, so our most important tasks keep running, but lower prio tasks can be interrupted. Also, even non RR tasks will be run at some time, as we don't use 100% of our CPU time on RR.

Comment: And you end up with the problem you are reporting. Should be convincing enough?

Comment: Yes - a problem that seems to be solvable by letting kworkers run at a higher priority. Why is this a bad idea?

Comment: Have you been able to confirm that it's the kworker that is being blocked? I'm not sure if there's a priority inheritance mechanism in the PREEMPT_RT kernel for kworkers, but it seems like there should be. If the driver uses interrupt handlers, are those at a higher priority than your application? Why is your application not sleeping (i.e. shouldn't it be blocking if it is waiting on TTY data)?

Comment: We've tried manually increasing the priority of the kworker, and it helps, so it's confirmed. The interrupt handler runs fine, I assume, it's just that the work queue is not handled. There are multiple threads - the TTY thread is sleeping.

Yes, a priority inheritance thing would be great, but I think it is missing. Finding out is part of this question though. How to enable it, if there is something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root-cause for this behaviour is `tty_flip_buffer_push()`

In [**`kernel/drivers/tty/tty_buffer.c:518`**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/tty_buffer.c?v=4.8#L518),
tty_flip_buffer_push schedules an asynchronous task. This is soon executed asynchronously by a kworker thread.

However, if any realtime threads execute on the system and keep it busy then the chance that the kworker thread will execute soon is very less. Eventually once the RT threads relinquish CPU or [RT-throttling](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Real_Time/7/html/Tuning_Guide/Real_Time_Throttling.html) is triggerred, it might eventually provide the kworker thread a chance to execute.

---

### Older kernels support the `low_latency` flag within the TTY sub-system.

Prior to **Linux kernel v3.15** [**`tty_flip_buffer_push()`**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/tty_buffer.c?v=3.14#L489) honored the `low_latency` flag of the tty port.

If the `low_latency` flag was set by the UART driver as follows (typically in its `.startup()` function),

```
t->uport.state->port.tty->low_latency = 1;
```

then `tty_flip_buffer_push()` perform a synchronous copy in the context of the current function call itself. Thus it automatically inherits the priority of the current task i.e. there is no chance of a priority inversion incurred by asynchronously scheduling a work task.

> Note:  If the serial driver sets the `low_latency` flag, it must avoid calling `tty_flip_buffer_push()` within an ISR(interrupt context). With the `low_latency` flag set, `tty_flip_buffer_push()` does NOT use separate workqueue, but directly calls the functions. So if called within an interrupt context, the ISR will take longer to execute. This will increase latency of other parts of the kernel/system. Also under certain conditions (dpeending on how much data is available in the serial buffer) `tty_flip_buffer_push()` may attempt to sleep (acquire a mutex). Calling sleep within an ISR in the Linux kernel causes a [kernel bug](http://linux-kernel.2935.n7.nabble.com/PATCH-USB-ftdi-sio-Remove-tty-gt-low-latency-td278898.html).

---

*With the workqueue implementation within the Linux kernel having migrated to [CMWQ](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/workqueue.html),

it is no longer possible to deterministically obtain independent execution contexts

(i.e. separate threads) for individual workqueues.*

*All workqueues in the system are backed by `kworker/*` threads in the system.*

***NOTE: THIS SECTION IS OBSOLETE!!***
*Leaving the following intact as a reference for older versions of the Linux kernel.*

### Customisations for low-latency/real-time UART/TTY:

#### 1. Create and use a personal workqueue for the TTY layer.

Create a new  workqueue in tty_init().

A workqueue created with `create_workqueue()` will have 1 worker thread for each CPU on the system.

```
struct workqueue_struct *create_workqueue(const char *name);
```

Using `create_singlethread_workqueue()` instead, creates a workqueue with a single kworker process

```
struct workqueue_struct *create_singlethread_workqueue(const char *name);
```

#### 2. Use the private workqueue.

Queue the flip buffer work on the above private workqueue instead of the kernel's global global workqueue.

```
int queue_work(struct workqueue_struct *queue, struct work_struct *work);
```

Replace `schedule_work()` with `queue_work()` in functions called by tty_flip_buffer_push().

#### 3. Tweak the execution priority of the private workqueue.

Upon boot the kworker thread being used by TTY layer workqueue can be identified by the string `name` used while creating it. Set an appropriate higher RT priority using `chrt` upon this thread as required by the system design.

Comment: Thanks! We also found a patch, which seems to do something similar, but using a kworker instead of a proper work queue.
The patch is here: http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-serial/msg17782.html

Seems to be the only way - sadly no ready made solution. Unless the linked patch gets integrated.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into exactly the same problem of when I developed on Linux.

The question and answers really helped me but in the end I chose a different approach. And it works fantastically for me.

Instead of adopting an invasive approach by changing Linux (as other answers), I chose to separate the threads into two groups.

The first group consists of the low priority and has heavy work tasks. These are not hard time-critical.
These tasks are the source of our problem (see my question here [UART linux stuck !!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76897228/linux-uart-read-in-non-blocking-mode-is-stuck-while-other-low-priority-thread-is/76911665#76911665)).

The second group consists of real-time tasks with real priorities.

The first thread group is configured to use the SCHED_OTHER scheduler and the other group tasks use SCHED_RR.

By using SCHED_OTHER for low-priority tasks, it resolves the problem.

See my answer in the question above. There is also a code example in the solution.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34915296)