# Linux Uart read in non-blocking mode is stuck while other low-priority thread is running

Tags: c, linux, uart

I have a project based on embedded linux.
My device communicates to another one through UART.
It periodically reads the serial port from a high-priority thread.
The port is configured to be in non-blocking mode.
It works fine but for some weird reasons, when a massive **low-priority** thread starts running, the read is blocking till it completes !!
I attach a picture of the threads.

[image: Uart read blocking]

I have tried configuring the port with several options but non of them helped.
I attach the code

```
bool UartCommDevice::OpenImpl(const char* portName, int baudRate, bool isBlockingMode, int timeoutBlock)
{
    m_serialPortName = portName;
    m_baudRate = baudRate;
    m_handle = open(m_serialPortName.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

    if (m_handle < 0)
    {
        m_handle = 0;
        std::cout << "error opening " << m_serialPortName << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    struct termios tty { 0 };

    if (tcgetattr(m_handle, &tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }

    // Set the baud rate for the serial port
    if (cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t) baudRate) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error from cfsetospeed: errno: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }

    if (cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)baudRate) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error from cfsetispeed: errno: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);    // ignore modem controls
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;         // 8-bit characters
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     // no parity bit
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;     // only need 1 stop bit
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    // no hardware flowcontrol

    // Setup for non-canonical mode
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    // Fetch bytes as they become available
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    tcflush(m_handle, TCIOFLUSH);

    if (tcsetattr(m_handle, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }

    if (flock(m_handle, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) == -1) 
    {
        printf("Serial port with file descriptor is already locked by another process.\r\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the incomplete code shown in the question? How did you check in which way the read thread is blocked? You should show a [mre]. If `flock` fails you only print a message, but don't handle the case in a specific way. BTW: I suggest to choose either `iostreams` output or `printf`. Error messages should be printed on `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Comment: Since the termios configuration is a copy of my code (w/o any attribution BTW), I don't expect it to be the cause of whatever problem you have. But you haven't made a case for using non-blocking mode, or shown that you're not wasting CPU cycles waiting for data to arrive. IOW you use non-blocking I/O, and then wonder why a thread seems to hog the CPU/resources?

Comment: Aside: Shouldn't you check the lock *before* you start flushing data and changing the settings? If you expect another process to respect the locked port, your code should respect it too.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was found and it is not related to the non-blocking or blocking modes.
It is due linux scheduler policies of the kernel tty driver (involving kworker).
For full information and deep understanding, refer to this question:
[Kworker threads getting blocked by SCHED_RR userspace threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977152/kworker-threads-getting-blocked-by-sched-rr-userspace-threads)

SOLUTION:
The working solution we have implemented is as following.
The tasks that are periodic Real-time and not heavy duty are assigned with scheduling policy SCHED_RR and the other - which are long and CPU consuming (with low-priority) - are set with SCHED_OTHER. SCHED_OTHER is the scheduler policy used by kworker...
Note that:

1. Thread scheduler settings (policy...) shall be set before the thread is started.
2. PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED shall be set

Here an excerpt of the code:

```
pthread_attr_t attr;

auto ret = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
if (ret != 0)
{
    return false;
}

sched_param param { 0 };
param.sched_priority = m_priority;


scheduler_policy = m_priority < rt_lowest_priority ? SCHED_OTHER : SCHED_RR;

pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);        // Don't inherit scheduler
pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, scheduler_policy);               // Set scheduler policy

pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param);

ret = pthread_create(
    &m_handle,
    &attr,
    InvokeTask,
    this);
```

This totally resolved our problem as the low priority tasks (which was assigned to SCHED_RR) is now running on SCHED_OTHER and don't hold the kworkers...

Here the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Increase priorities for serial IRQ and kworker related to push driver buffer to tty-layer line discipline.

But be careful, because this **worker is shared unbounded between kernel tasks.**

Comment: I think it is very not recommended to modify the kernel. See above for our solution

Answer (score 0):

That's amazing and very interesting. So much work to make work a simple sensitive uart for realtime linux. The low latency backport patch from older kernel is the only solution... I think this shall be include direclty into Linux preempt-rt patch.
I think that by removing low-latency function from old kernel was a mistake.

Five years ago, when I met this latency problem on lttng tracer (yours is Spyker isn't It?), I have chosen to increase the original kworker priority. It makes the job but all other kernel tasks which used this worker were speed up too (impacts have to be rationalized).

Comment: Cohen, let me know which type of serial protocol you used to get such as sensitiveness, canonical or non-canonical? I think you used canonic one with framing protocol (EOF with kind of ASCII breaks).                                                   I have now some troubles with the non-canonical one. Please check this link, Muller gave me a headache...https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/754975/how-to-patch-kernel-to-reduce-vtime-gap-for-uart-termios-api

Comment: Our protocol is non-canonical. It is binary.

Comment: https://youtu.be/g4sZUBS57OQ?feature=shared

Comment: @PANIK Please, can you write what's your intention and point on the relevant section? Thanks.